# Why www.mydomaim.com not working for wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, hosting, openshift

I have wordpress website on openshift cloud. URL mydomain.rhcloud.com or http://mydomain.rhcloud.com work fine in browser.But when site access through **www**.mydomain.rhcloud.com URL "server is not find" shown.why this happen?

Comment: Because www.mydomain.rhcloud.com is not the same as mydomain.rhcloud.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no record created for www.mydomain.rhcloud.com, only app-domain.rhcloud.com.  if you want to add your OWN domain name like www.example.com, you need to purchase it, then add an alias to your app-domain.rhcloud.com, and setup your dns for www.example.com to point to it using a CNAME record.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the original domain name here is "rhcloud.com" and that "mydomain" is just a subdomain. In this case, "www.mydomain" is a different subdomain and it cannot be redirected to "mydomain.rhcloud.com".

To make this work, you should grant "www.mydomain" subdomain and either put your site there or make it redirect automatically to "mydomain".